# How does inetd transfer control to respective services?

Tags: linux, process, inetd

How does [inetd](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inetd) transfer control to the service, Below is my understanding

- inetd listens on every port mentioned in `/etc/inetd.conf`
- If a client make a request to one of the port that inetd listens then inetd transfers control of that request to a service by spinning it as a child process by looking `/etc/inetd.conf`
- It is acts as multiplexer.

My doubt is below

- How the request is handover to the child process (respective service daemon)?
- Already connection is made on the port by inetd so child process can't that port again until the inetd releases that port. If inetd releases that port then existing client connection will be droped (kindly correct me if my understanding is wrong).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`inetd` listens on a port, and then connects it to the stdin, stdout, and stderr of the service that will process it.

## How does it do it

- After `accept`ing the connection, it has a socket on one of its `fd`s.
- It will then `dup`licate the `fd` to `0`,`1`,and `2`.
- It will then `fork`. All file descriptors will remain open, unless some action is taken to close them (so 0,1, and 2 remain open).
- The child process will then call `exec`, `fd`s still remain open.
- The service is now running with the remote client connected to stdin (0), stdout (1), and stderr (2).
- The service just needs to know that the client is on these file-descriptors, and not do a `listen` of its own.

(I did some searching, but can't see `inetd` telling the service program that it was called by `inetd`. I would expect a command line argument.)

Comment: You shouldn't really expect a command-line argument.  Interacting with standard I/O is not some special non-default mode.  Even picking up the port and address information can be done within the normal Unix framework.  http://jdebp.uk./FGA/UCSPI.html

Comment: @JdeBP so how does the server know that it has been started with the client on stdin/out/err? Does the process have to introspect the fd, to see what type it is?

Comment: You are still assuming modality.  This is not a special non-default mode that a program has to detect and enter.  This is the program behaving normally, interacting with its standard I/O, which just happens to be sockets but for most application protocols does not actually have to be.

Comment: @JdeBP yes most programs interact with stdin/out/err. But a network server, may be used with or without inetd. If without, then it would not use stdin/out.

Comment: If used without inetd it still uses standard I/O, and ends up speaking its protocol with something that isn't a socket, or terminating with a fatal error because some socket API call has failed on file descriptor 0 (as, for example, `in.talkd` does).

Answer (score 0):

Consider actions like this:

[parent]

```
sfd = socket(), listen(), connect(), fork();
```

For other descriptors that should not be inherited by child processes,
`close()` or previously set them to `FD_CLOEXEC;` after `fork`, parent could close this sfd

[child]

`execve();` copy of connected socket descriptor inherited, can use for client I/O

Comment: ahhh, nice point. tnx @forest.

Comment: I don't understand this answer, and I know roughly what happens.

Answer (score 0):

It is neatly explained in [Que-Linux-Socket-Programming](http://read.pudn.com/downloads166/ebook/759178/Que-Linux-Socket-Programming.pdf) under the section `The Design Parameters of inetd Servers`